# Add number values from two columns into one

Tags: oracle, sum

I get `(null)` in "Debit" column, why ?

```
SELECT head_name, jv_acc_name, SUM (debit + credit) AS "Debit"
  FROM voucher_detail
  WHERE head_name IN (SELECT name_desc
                        FROM account_heads
                        WHERE acc_name = 'Assets')
GROUP BY head_name, jv_acc_name;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or what?

Comment: Please take a few moments and add a problem statement to your question.

Comment: That query looks OK to me.

Comment: I bet there are nulls in columns `debit`/`credit`. Try `sum(nvl(debit, 0) + nvl(credit, 0))`

Comment: Please provide the sample data.

Comment: Dmitry , you win the bet :) there is null values as well in both columns, with nvl function its working now , thanx dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try check for null  and assign 0

```
SELECT head_name, jv_acc_name, SUM (nvl(debit,0) + nvl(credit,0)) AS "Debit"
FROM voucher_detail
WHERE head_name IN (SELECT name_desc
                    FROM account_heads
                    WHERE acc_name = 'Assets')
GROUP BY head_name, jv_acc_name;
```